# Unable to empty() on combo boxes Jquery Mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I am using Jquery Mobile for my project . When i use `.empty()` to clear all the contents inside combo boxes it is not working.

MY Code:

```
<select name="select-choice-a1" data-native-menu="false" id="vj">
                    <option>Custom menu example</option>
                    <option value="standard">Standard: 7 day</option>
                    <option value="rush">Rush: 3 days</option>
                    <option value="express">Express: next day</option>
                    <option value="overnight">Overnight</option>
                </select>
```

Javascript:

```
$("#vj").empty();
```

And am calling this after deviceready only.

When the page loads the html i gave is changed as

```
<div class="ui-content" data-role="main">

                <a class="ui-btn ui-btn-inline ui-corner-all ui-shadow" href="#myPanel">Add Location</a>

                <label class="select" for="select-choice-a1">Select Location</label>
                <div class="ui-select"><a href="#" role="button" id="vj-button" aria-haspopup="true" class="ui-btn ui-icon-carat-d ui-btn-icon-right ui-corner-all ui-shadow"><span>Custom menu example</span></a><select id="vj" data-native-menu="false" name="select-choice-a1" tabindex="-1">
                    <option data-placeholder="true">Custom menu example</option>
                    <option value="standard">Standard: 7 day</option>
                    <option value="rush">Rush: 3 days</option>
                    <option value="express">Express: next day</option>
                    <option value="overnight">Overnight</option>
                </select><div style="display: none;" id="vj-listbox-placeholder"><!-- placeholder for vj-listbox --></div></div>

                <label class="ui-hidden-accessible" for="textinput-hide">RFID:</label>
                <div class="ui-input-text ui-body-inherit ui-corner-all ui-shadow-inset"><input type="text" value="" placeholder="Text input" name="textinput-hide"></div>

                <label class="ui-hidden-accessible" for="textinput-hide">Details:</label>
                <div class="ui-input-text ui-body-inherit ui-corner-all ui-shadow-inset"><input type="text" value="" placeholder="Text input" name="textinput-hide"></div>

            </div>
```

Comment: Your code works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/yL2cn8g8/. You may need to add more context (in the JS) to see where it is failing. What do you see in the error log?

Comment: Okay the problem is if i give data-native-menu="false" i am unable to clear combo box

Comment: I updated the jsfiddle with your code (http://jsfiddle.net/yL2cn8g8/4/) and it works fine with `data-native-menu="false"`. Again, you need to add more of the JavaScript context and the logs to see if something around the `$("#vj").empty();` is failing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is [custom selectmenu](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.5/selectmenu-custom/) converted into a popup. I guess `.empty()` wouldn't not work without [destroying](http://api.jquerymobile.com/selectmenu/#method-destroy) the selectmenu and create it from the scratch.

So you have to do the following.

```
$("#vj")
    .selectmenu("destroy") // destory it
    .empty();              // remove options
```

After that, add new options.

```
$("#vj").append("<option>");
```

When you finish adding new options, make sure to create it again using `.selectmenu()` function.

```
$("#vj").selectmenu();
```

See it working in this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7rcz8p9t/).

Answer (score 1):

Any time you change the contents of a jQuery Mobile selectmenu widget, you need to tell jQM to refresh the widget:

```
$( ".selector" ).selectmenu( "refresh", true );
```

API: http://api.jquerymobile.com/selectmenu/#method-refresh

For your case:

```
$("#vj").empty().selectmenu( "refresh", true );
```

Passing in true forces jQM to rebuild the widget, so you don't need to destroy and reinitialize.